# Can't fetch URL from database Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Hi everyone in the database a column called attachments stores data like this

```
"a:3:{s:6:\"saveTo\";s:7:\"wpmedia\";s:14:\"attachmentType\";s:6:\"images\";s:11:\"attachments\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:12:\"attachmentId\";i:176165;s:4:\"file\";s:68:\"https://www.yallamission.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/MG_00283.jpg\";s:8:\"fileName\";s:12:\"MG_00283.jpg\";s:9:\"thumbnail\";s:76:\"https://www.yallamission.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/MG_00283-150x150.jpg\";s:8:\"fileSize\";s:9:\"292.85 KB\";s:8:\"fileType\";s:10:\"image/jpeg\";}}}
```

i need to fetch the image url only yet i am unable to do it successfully as i don't understand this format

I tried to use php functions and substr() yet the text before and after has dynamic content and no fixed standard.

Comment: It's a serialized string, so you need [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: its called serialized string, use  [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to decode it as an array. http://tpcg.io/_91SZZ2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is serialized data and you can unserialize them and access the attachments by using `unserialize($variable)` and access the attachment elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` instead of `serialize` when building the data for INSERTing.  Then use the JSON functions in SQL (if your MySQL is new enough).